# Setting up Zend Framework - MVC

Tags: zend-framework

I have developed numerous websites using Codeigniter, but now have the need to migrate to Zend Framework.
I am installing it on shared hosting and I have virtually no command line experience. So far I have downloaded the framework, unzipped it and uploaded it to the hosting. I am using a Centos server provided by Godaddy.

I have tried the quick start guide but this uses command line, I also notice there is no index file to route requests through.
Is there a way that I can set up a basic MVC structure without using command line or do you have any pointers for what I need to be doing next.

Thanks in advance.

John

Comment: visit : www.zendcasts.com for good resources about starting with ZF

Comment: You could install it locally on your computer with servers like WAMP or XAMP and run the commands to create the structure on your computer and then upload the folder/files structure on your remote host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the command line tool. You can create files by yourself too. It's just more work for you ;) So for a basic setting you'd have to create the folders/files listed [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html). The command line tool only saves you a lot of create/copy & paste work. The code for all files is listed in the quickstart, but a bit spread over the different pages. I'd suggest to read everything first to get the idea of how zf does work and then create all files.

The index file responsible for all routing is `public/index.php`.